# while loop doesn't end even when the condition is right

Tags: python, while-loop

I am doing a login system. It asks the user to answer the question ('Do you already have an account? ') and while the answer isn't yes or no it should continue asking.

```
print('Welcome to the quiz!')
print('Do you already have an account? ')
have_acc = input()
while have_acc != ('Yes') or have_acc != ('No') or have_acc != ('yes') or have_acc != ('no'):
    print('Please enter Yes or No')
    have_acc = input()
```

OUTPUT

```
Welcome to the quiz!
Do you already have an account? 
yes
Please enter Yes or No
no
Please enter Yes or No
Yes
Please enter Yes or No
No
Please enter Yes or No
```

Comment: Change all of the `or` to `and`.  You can also remove the parentheses, they're useless and unnatural.

Comment: Take a look at [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Don't worry, all programmers make this mistake at least once. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more canonical approach:

```
while input.lower() not in ('yes', 'no',):
    ... your retry code ...
```

Comment: i deleted my answer,..., same as yours

Comment: damn, got there before me... +1
you have a superfluous comma in the tuple literal however.

Comment: this site get ridiculous sometime, ... , it's more like logic error than python or while loop as tagged

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the logic. ‘Yes’ != ‘No’, so one of the conditions will always be hit. I am not familiar with python syntax, logically what you need is:

```
while not (input == ‘Yes’ or input == ‘No’)
```

At this point, any single match would be good

Answer (score 0):

Your `while`-loop condition is flawed, as say I enter `Yes`, it'll evaluate the conditional from left-to-right and notice the `have_acc != ('Yes')`, but then since it's preceded with an `or` keyword, it'll evaluate the rest of the conditions-- if one is `True` then it'll run the code in the `while` loop, the problem here is that `have_acc != ('No')` will evaluate to `True` as `('Yes' != 'No') == True` so the entire statement will evaluate as `True`, thenceforth executing the code in the loop.

What you'd want to do is a cleaner and more minimalistic version of this which is less error-prone such as this:

```
print('Welcome to the quiz!')
print('Do you already have an account? ')
have_acc = input().lower()

while have_acc not in ('yes', 'no'):
    print('Please enter "yes" or "no"')
    have_acc = input().lower()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this statement 
While have_acc == "yes" or have_acc == "no" 
     have_acc
elif: 
      Print("please enter yes or no")